# MPMusicPlayerController volum not changing

Tags: ios, volume, uislider, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'm creating an radio application in ios. I want to change the volum by using a slider. So I defined an `IBAction` (`- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged  : (UISlider *)sender`) and drag the
`Value Changed` event of the slider to this `IBAction`.

This is my `IBAction` implementation
`

```
 - (IBAction)sliderValueChanged  : (UISlider *)sender
```

{

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:sender.value];
```

}`

But when I drag the slider volum is not changing. Any one can tell me what is the problem with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First declare your musicplayer in .h file.

```
MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer;
```

in `viewDidLoad` you can define it.

```
self.musicPlayer=[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];

// musicPlayer.volume = 0.5f;

 - (IBAction)sliderValueChanged  : (UISlider *)sender
{
 musicPlayer.volume=sender.value;
}
```

Try changing volume by giving static value then go for dynamic.

Comment: It displays slider value is changing. But I cant hear a volum change. If value is changing should it be ok? Or else there will be another reason for this?

Comment: still I'm testing in the semulator

Comment: in your slider Action give some static value. like  musicPlayer.volume = 0.5f; And try to vary the value like 0.8f, 0.9f and test how is it Producing O/P.

Comment: you can try this also `[self.musicPlayer setVolume:[[NSNumber numberWithDouble:sender.value] floatValue]` inside your slider Action.

Answer (score 0):

Try use this code

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer] setVolume:sender.value];
```

Comment: I tried this also but still same. I test this with the semulator. Is it the problem?